# DialogFragment returning NullPointer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pick time following this guide: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

But I'm getting this error:

> 01-11 19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-11 19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-11 19:37:58.513:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:228) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   iuAndroid.Informe$TimePickerFragment.showTimePickerDialog(Informe.java:126)
>   01-11 19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   iuAndroid.Informe$1.onClick(Informe.java:80) 01-11 19:37:58.513:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 01-11 19:37:58.513:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-11 19:37:58.513:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 01-11 19:37:58.513:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   01-11 19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 01-11
>   19:37:58.513: E/AndroidRuntime(2419):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My class timePicker:

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(final TimePicker view, final int hourOfDay, final int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(final View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}

}
```

When I do: `newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");`
it returns a NullPointer..

And this is the part of my layout:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/from_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/from_name"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/timeFrom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"        
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner"
    />
 <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/to_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/to_name"/>

 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/timeTo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner"
    />
```

Comment: What's in your `iuAndroid.Informe$1.onClick()`? Since you seem to be having a non-static factory-like method `showTimePickerDialog()` (you shouldn't), you're possibly calling it on an badly initialized object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPE in `.show()` is usually thrown when we pass fragment manager as null. This might happen in your case if TimePickerFragment was not yet attached to the activity in the moment of calling `showTimePickerDialog()`.

I suggest that you define `showTimePickerDialog()` as static and as argument use Fragment Manager. Currently i have feeling that you first call `new TimePickerFragment()` before calling this method, and then again in this method. So you are instantiating object twice and this is not needed.

```
public static void showTimePickerDialog(final FragmentManager manager) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(manager, "timePicker");
}
```

You can then call from your activity:

```
TimePickerFragment.showTimePickerDialog(getFragmentManager());
```